# Datagrid and observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have an Observable collection of packet list of type packet. Each packet consists of 3 different observable collections of type data. These 3 different observable collections are header class, frame class and tail class. I am trying to extract the values of the type data and place them under one column in the datagrid. Same for frame and tail. However, how do i go about doing the binding of an observableCollection of data under one column?

```
namespace macframe
{
    public class Packet
    {
    private ObservableCollection<Packet> items;
    private Header header;
    private Frame frame;
    private Tail tail;

    public Packet(Header header, Frame frame, Tail tail)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.frame = frame;
        this.tail = tail;
        items = new ObservableCollection<Packet>();
    }
}

public class Data
{
  private String sDatavalue;
  public Data(String datavalue)
  {
      this.sDatavalue = datavalue;
  }

  public string datavalue
  {
      get { return sDatavalue; }
      set { sDatavalue = datavalue; }
  }
}


public class Header
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> headerItems;

    public Header()
    {
        headerItems = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Data> header
    { get { return headerItems; } }
}

public class Frame
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> frameItems;

    public Frame()
    {
        frameItems = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Data> frame
    { get { return frameItems; } }
}

public class Tail
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> tailItems;

    public Tail()
    {
        tailItems = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Data> tail
    { get { return tailItems; } }
}
```

}

```
<Window x:Class="macframe.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgrid">

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Packet class?

Comment: code is as updated. i wonder if a datagrid is able to display the contents of my header, frame or tail class without checking the type of data?

Comment: can you show the XAML of the DataGrid as well?

Comment: i did not add the dgrid.DataContext statement yet because i am not sure on how to present as of my question above

Comment: Just to be clear here - `Header`, `Frame` and `Tail` are all classes that contain an `ObservableCollection<Data>`?  Do they contain anything else?  Are you wanting to have a column in the datagrid for `Header`, one for `Frame` and one for `Tail`?  Is that correct?

Comment: You should merge your 3 collections into 1 collection in order to bind it to the DataGrid. It can be achieved using some kind of a view model. Also it is still unclear to me why you have the inner collection of the `Packet` class inside the `Packet` class.

Comment: @Zannjaminderson yes that is what i want to achieve but because my tail header and frame consists of class data. so i not sure if my table is able to display the strings of the data correctly or not.

Comment: @vorrtex oh can you explain about the inner collection of the Packet class inside the Packet class? I am a newbie at this sorry

Comment: @edelweiss I tried to clarify why did you use this code `public class Packet { private ObservableCollection<Packet> items;`. As you see there is some kind of recursive collection and I don't know what is the reason of using it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your intention right, you want a single grid to display three different collections, each one independent from the other two. That is, to cut matters short, impossible.

You can bind your Grid to **one source only** (set the ItemsSource Property), and that has to be a collection type in order to get it to work (WPF auto-generates a CollectionView around properties bound to ItemsControls).

If there's a way to relate your Data in a flat way, you should do that. But to me, it looks like your intention is to display hierarchical data...Please provide a short list of sample records (fake data is fairly enough), so we can see what you expect your grid to look like.